# Getting Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server When trying to run a batch script

Tags: sql-server, xampp, odbc

I am using XAMPP for creating a local SQL Server instance to run a SQL script. the issue here is, when I run the script I get the following error. What is going wrong here?

Code:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -d mysqldb -U uname -P pass -i C:\query2.sql
PAUSE
```

Error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: Have you installed a Microsoft SQL Server instance? Because `sqlcmd` doesn't do that, it's just a command line client.

Comment: @Alwayslearning - I am using Xampp to run a sql instance

Comment: XAMPP typically installs MySQL or MariaDB. So have you installed a Microsoft SQL Server instance?

Comment: Yeah, here is the connection string to SQL server 2019 instance. Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True; But I have used Microsoft sql workbench IDE to develop the sql script wch is using MYSQL connection that i started through XAMPP. I dont understand what am i missing here. :(

Comment: Server name is 'PF24DCW6\SQLEXPRESS' on MSSQL server, but i am trying to connect to the localhost wch is running mysql and that is where i have connected with MySQl workbench where i have created my database. @AlwaysLearning

Comment: sqlcmd is for SQL Server, you can't connect to MySQL with it. They are completely different database products.

Comment: Also, there is no "Microsoft sql workbench IDE". There is one for MySQL thought...

Comment: @james, Yeah, that's where I got confused and now I am running MYSQL cmd to execute the script.
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u un  -p pwd -D mysqldb < path to query.sql
here it is considering what i am mentioned under -p as DB and prompting for password. How to rectify that ?

Answer (score 0):

sqlcmd is for SQL Server, you i couldn't connect to MySQL with it as @james Z mentioned. They are completely different database products. I tried using mysql commmand

C:\Software\XAMPP\mysql\bin\mysql --host=hostname --port=portnumber -D dbname  -u username --password=**** < path to sql file